# Preventing three SQL Left Joins from creating duplicate rows

Tags: join, duplication, sql-server-2019

I have 4 tables `[tA]` is the main data point. A customer could have more than one ID Code, or the same ID Code which has been renewed, and ID Codes can be transferred between customers, but a customer shouldn't have more than one at the same time. The ID Code Category and the Code Owner should be the same within this data-set if the ID Code appears more than once.

I want to be able to add `EIDCodeCategory` from `tB`, `CodeOwnerE` from `tC` and `CodeOwnerG` from `tD` onto `tA` matching on the ID code. There will be duplicates due to renewals which is why the left joins aren't working.

The tables:

```
CREATE TABLE tA
(
       Customer_Number bigint(12)
      ,ID_Code varchar(12)
      ,Effective_from_Date date
      ,Effective_to_Date date
);

CREATE TABLE tB
(
      EIDCode varchar(12)
     ,EIDCodeCategory char
);

CREATE TABLE tC
(
      IDCodeE varchar(12)
     ,CodeOwnerE varchar(3)
);

CREATE TABLE tD
(
      IDCodeG varchar(12)
     ,CodeOwnerG varchar(3)
);
```

Sample data:

```
INSERT INTO tA (Customer_Number, ID_Code, Effective_from_Date, Effective_to_Date)
VALUES (9952203, 'M06508A6', '2012-01-17', '2020-09-11')
      ,(9952203, 'M06508A6', '2020-09-12', NULL)
      ,(9868102, 'G4A11001', '2015-12-17', NULL)
      ,(9727022, 'G921255', '2016-05-24', '2020-09-11')
      ,(9727022, 'UNKNOWN', '2020-09-12', '2020-11-10')
      ,(9077077, 'G921255', '1998-06-10', '2016-05-23')

INSERT INTO tB (EIDCode, EIDCodeCategory)
VALUES ('M06508A6', 'C')
       ('G4A11001', 'B')
       ('G921255', 'C')

INSERT INTO tC (IDCodeE, CodeOwnerE)
VALUES ('G4A11001', 'FLC')
       ('G921255', 'MGN')

INSERT INTO tD (IDCodeG, CodeOwnerG)
VALUES ('M06508A6', 'GNG')
```

Original query:

```
SELECT
       [DB1].[dbo].[tA].[Customer_Number], [ID_Code], [Effective_from_Date], [Effective_to_Date]
      ,[DB2].[dbo].[tB].[EIDCodeCategory]
      ,[DB1].[dbo].[tC].[CodeOwnerE]
      ,[DB1].[dbo].[tD].[CodeOwnerG]
FROM ((([DB1].[dbo].[tA]

LEFT OUTER JOIN [DB2].[dbo].[tB]
ON [DB1].[dbo].[tA].[ID_Code] = [DB2].[dbo].[tB].[EIDCode]
AND ID_Code != 'UNKNOWN')

LEFT OUTER JOIN [DB1].[dbo].[tC]
ON [DB1].[dbo].[tA].[ID_Code] = [DB1].[dbo].[tC].[IDCodeE]
AND ID_Code != 'UNKNOWN')

LEFT OUTER JOIN [DB1].[dbo].[tD]
ON  [DB1].[dbo].[tA].[ID_Code] = [DB1].[dbo].[tD].[IDCodeG]
AND ID_Code != 'UNKNOWN')

ORDER BY Customer_Number DESC;
```

The result I'm getting:

```
+-----------------+----------+---------------------+-------------------+-----------------+------------+------------+
| Customer_Number | ID_Code  | Effective_from_Date | Effective_to_Date | EIDCodeCategory | CodeOwnerE | CodeOwnerG |
+-----------------+----------+---------------------+-------------------+-----------------+------------+------------+
|         9952203 | M06508A6 | 2012-01-17          | 2020-09-11        | C               |            | GNG        |
|         9952203 | M06508A6 | 2012-01-17          | 2020-09-11        | C               |            |            |
|         9952203 | M06508A6 | 2020-09-12          |                   | C               |            | GNG        |
|         9952203 | M06508A6 | 2020-09-12          |                   | C               |            |            |
|         9868102 | G4A11001 | 2015-12-17          |                   | B               | FLC        |            |
|         9727022 | G921255  | 2016-05-24          | 2020-09-11        | C               | MGN        |            |
|         9727022 | G921255  | 2016-05-24          | 2020-09-11        | C               | MGN        |            |
|         9727022 | UNKNOWN  | 2020-09-12          | 2020-11-10        |                 |            |            |
|         9077077 | G921255  | 1998-06-10          | 2016-05-23        | C               | MGN        |            |
|         9077077 | G921255  | 1998-06-10          | 2016-05-23        | C               | MGN        |            |
|                 |          |                     |                   |                 |            |            |
+-----------------+----------+---------------------+-------------------+-----------------+------------+------------+
```

The result I'm after:

```
+-----------------+----------+---------------------+-------------------+-----------------+------------+------------+
| Customer_Number | ID_Code  | Effective_from_Date | Effective_to_Date | EIDCodeCategory | CodeOwnerE | CodeOwnerG |
+-----------------+----------+---------------------+-------------------+-----------------+------------+------------+
|         9952203 | M06508A6 | 2012-01-17          | 2020-09-11        | C               |            | GNG        |
|         9952203 | M06508A6 | 2020-09-12          |                   | C               |            | GNG        |
|         9868102 | G4A11001 | 2015-12-17          |                   | B               | FLC        |            |
|         9727022 | G921255  | 2016-05-24          | 2020-09-11        | C               | MGN        |            |
|         9727022 | UNKNOWN  | 2020-09-12          | 2020-11-10        |                 |            |            |
|         9077077 | G921255  | 1998-06-10          | 2016-05-23        | C               | MGN        |            |
+-----------------+----------+---------------------+-------------------+-----------------+------------+------------+
```

How can I join these columns from `tB`, `tC` and `tD` onto `tA` matching against their common ID Code without duplicating results? (equivalent = I'm a SQL newbie and work mainly in Excel - would normally just do an INDEX match). I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18.4.

Comment: Thanks for the edit!  It would be great if you could add the `CREATE TABLE` statements for the tables involved, along with some sample data via `INSERT INTO` statements.  As it stands the question is wordy and difficult to comprehend specifically where the issue is.  Adding those details would make it much simpler for someone unfamiliar with your setup to provide an answer.  As in my previous comment, take a look at [mcve] for an example of how to do that.

Comment: On of these tables (tB, tC or tD) contains more than one record for ID_Code = M0658A6 (or tA contains duplicates for the same period EFD-EDT).

Comment: It works fine in https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=14d062dc39e4fa57a9ab3bd4e32bf2f5
Looks like you have added some duplicate data in some of the tables.

Comment: Also there are missing commas and statement terminators in your INSERT statements

Comment: And what is that (12) in `bigint(12)`? Doesn't look like SQL Server syntax.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ  apologies, I've had to recreate the data as the tables themselves weren't actually created by me and there are over 700,000 entries in the original databases.  I know there are duplicates in the original tables which is why left joins aren't working - I'm trying to find a work-around so that I can match them without creating even more duplicates. Not sure if it can be done though

Comment: Is `(EIDCode)` unique in `tB`? Is there a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint on it? The same question for `tC` and `tD`.